# Ionic 3 virtualscroll failing to render properly on scroll (video)

Tags: angular, ionic3, virtualscroll

In the previous ionic version, I had some problems with the virtual scroll (items being rendered overlapping and taking forever to render properly).

Since the last update, it is getting even worse, where scrolling would make the virtualscroll not rendering properly.

Here is a screen cap:
https://youtu.be/tfYSLy6p-y01

Here is a snippet of my code. All properties are properly filled and the height and width of the mzk-thumb are locked in CSS.

```
                <ion-content (ionScroll)="onScroll($event);"
                             [hidden]="!(!timedout && !loading && medias.length!==0)"
                >

                    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="medias"
                              [approxItemHeight]="iconHeight+ 'px'"
                              [approxItemWidth]="iconWidth + 'px'">
                        <div *virtualItem="let item">
                            <mzk-thumb
                                [media]="item">
                            </mzk-thumb>
                        </div>
                    </ion-list>
                </ion-content>
```

the “medias” object isn’t modified after being set either…

For info:

cli packages: (/Users/millerf/Documents/www/Mozaik/mzk_app/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
Node       : v8.7.0
npm        : 5.5.1 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: The youtube link to the screencap is broken.

Comment: @99tharun Oups! It should be available now

Comment: You are using float: left on the div wrapping the thumbnail, right?
I think virtual scroll works properly only if the items of the list are aligned vertically.

Comment: I dont use the float, as I figured out virtualscroll positions the items by itself.
I would think it would manage it better if they weren't vertical, as you can pass a 'width' for the items...